# error: default argument given for parameter 1

Tags: c++, function, default-arguments

I'm getting this error message with the code below:

```
class Money {
public:
    Money(float amount, int moneyType);
    string asString(bool shortVersion=true);
private:
    float amount;
    int moneyType;
};
```

First I thought that default parameters are not allowed as a first parameter in C++ but it is allowed.

Comment: Could you give a bit more details?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse CDT with MinGW 5.1.6 on Windows.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

You are probably redefining the default parameter in the implementation of the function. It should only be defined in the function declaration.

```
//bad (this won't compile)
string Money::asString(bool shortVersion=true){
}

//good (The default parameter is commented out, but you can remove it totally)
string Money::asString(bool shortVersion /*=true*/){
}

//also fine, but maybe less clear as the commented out default parameter is removed
string Money::asString(bool shortVersion){
}
```

Comment: Now it says:

string Money::asString()' does not match any in class `Money'

Comment: @pocoa You still need to keep the `bool shortVersion` parameter, just remove or comment out the `= true`

Comment: @Yacoby: Thanks, you were right. It doesn't make any sense, very confusing.

Comment: @pocoa: Actually, it does make sense. If you give default values for parameters, these are filled in at the _caller_. So they _have_ to be in the function's declaration, because this is what the callers need to see. If you had to repeat them at the _definition_ it would be redundant and more hassle to maintain. (This is also why I disagree with Yacoby about commenting out the default parameters in the implementation. IME, in real projects such comments will be out of sync with the declaration sooner or later.

Comment: When the interface and implementations are different from each other, it's making it harder to remember the actual definition. So you need to check the header file every time. Actually I liked the second usage, which comments the default parameter.

Comment: The actual definition is `std::string Money::asString(bool)`. Note that it doesn't even include the parameter's name. And, indeed, you can use different names in the declaration than in the definition. (This is important in huge project when - for whatever reasons - you want to change the name in the definition, but don't want to recompile millions of lines of code which depend on the declaration.)

Answer (score 16):

I made a similar error recently. this is how I resolved it.

when having a function prototype and definition. **the default parameter is not specified in the definition.**

eg:

```
int addto(int x, int y = 4);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int res = addto(5);
}

int addto(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```